# How to use Android network access, threads and handlers

Tags: android, multithreading, network-programming, handler

Trying to write my first Android application, and my starting point is to have the application read a text file from my website, and display it in the application.

I've given the application network access, and found network access cannot be made from the main thread, however also found that separate threads can't make changes to TextViews. Tried to implement the Handler, and everything fell apart.

I used a global variable triggered by a button instead so the main thread could update the TextView, but then when I added a timer into the mix to run the same thread, the TextView is coming up blank or crashing.

Could you outline the recommended steps/code that would do this, as I'm struggling to put all the components together to get me started?

UPDATE: This is the working code I put together:

```
private class GetUpdate extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params){
        try {
            URL urlObj = new URL("https://webpage.com");
            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));

            String temp = br.readLine();
            UpdateInfo = UpdateInfo + br.readLine();
        }
        catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException e) {
            UpdateInfo = UpdateInfo + "No Network";
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            UpdateInfo = UpdateInfo + "Failed";
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return "";
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        TextView StatusText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.StatusText);
        StatusText.setText(UpdateInfo);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
        UpdateInfo = "Status -\n\r" + currentDateandTime + " - ";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
    }
```

And the Timer located within onCreate:

```
    Timer myTimer = new Timer();
    myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new GetUpdate().execute("");
        }
    }, 0, 5000);
```

Comment: specify the error properly

Comment: Such questions are answered in Android documentation and book about Android development. Please go throught them firstly

Comment: @Sonesh Look you can not do network stuffs on the main thread so i suggest you to go for the async task and then set your textview from   async task

Comment: Handler is probably to low level for you. Start with [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) - study the documentation and try to use it.

Comment: There have been many over the last few days which I've cleared and replaced with others, but I've butchered my code so much I've scrapped it to start again. I'm normally a VB programmer, and I'm finding Java a lot more complicated with the separate mandatory threads. Main error is that I have found information about threads, and network access, and setText, but nothing that actually puts it together

Comment: I've not come across AsyncTask yet. I'll look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an Example:-

On your oncreate method do this

```
txtMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_push_message);
```

new task().execute();

```
 class task extends AsyncTask<String, String,String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        txtMessage.setText("Hi there");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        //Do something related to get the data and return that
        //Return the proper value
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I've updated my question with the code combining all the parts I need

Comment: @Sonesh Cool, Happy to help you...